# Coordinate system $(a,\tau)$ for butterfly circles?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Consider this picture

[image]

which shows a coordinate system $(a,\tau)$ on the Cartesian coordinate frame $(x,y)$, which is very similar to the bipolar coordinate system, with isosurfaces (i.e. circles) $\tau$ and their respective foci $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$.

Can anyone help me derive formulae on how I might be able to go from Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto (a,\tau)$ or polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)\mapsto (a,\tau)$, similar to what you might find on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates?

Essentially, this problem arose because I'd like to sample a function of the form $f(\rho,\theta)=g(C\rho(\cos\theta,\sin\theta-1))$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bipolar coordinates, could you elaborate on what you expect $\tau$ to be geometrically? Glancing at the Wikipedia article it appears $\tau$ is deeply intertwined with the geometric constraints of the coordinate system, but from what I can tell in the picture, it seems as though the coordinate space you're describing is the union of circles centered at $(\pm a,\ 0)$ with radius $a$. Am I misinterpreting you?

Comment: @user3002473 That is correct; those are indeed circles centered at $(\pm a,0)$.

Comment: Then the essential observation is that every point $(x,\ y)$ satisfies $(x - a)^2 + y^2 = a^2$ for some $a$. Solving yields $a = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2x}$. You would have to give more detail for me to help determine $\tau$, as I still don't think I understand you. When you say that the "isosurfaces" are $\tau$, do you mean that the circles are the surfaces traced out when $\tau$ is held constant and $a$ is varied?

Comment: @user3002473 In hindsight, I don't think "isosurfaces" was the right word. The $\tau$ would be the circles that are traces out when $\tau$ is held constant and $a$ is varied.

Comment: See [**6-sphere coordinates**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/6-SphereCoordinates.html), your case is just taking $z=w=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have one family of curves $(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$. Calculating the partial derivatives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{\partial a}{\partial x},\frac{\partial a}{\partial y} \right) = \left( \frac{x^2-y^2 }{2 x^2},\frac{y}{x} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
We need a vector that is orthogonal to this
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{\partial a}{\partial x},\frac{\partial a}{\partial y} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial b}{\partial x},\frac{\partial b}{\partial y} \right) =0
\end{eqnarray*}
So we need to solve the differential equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (x^2-y^2) \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}+ 2xy \frac{\partial b}{\partial y} =0
\end{eqnarray*}
Which is equivalent to solving
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{ (x^2-y^2)}{  2xy } 
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $y=ux$ and after a little calculus & algebra (& neat choice of arbitary constant)
\begin{eqnarray*}
x =\frac{2 bu}{  (1+u^2) } 
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 +(y-b)^2=b^2 
\end{eqnarray*}
So the other family of curves comes out to be circles as well ! ... but this time their centers run up the y-axis.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 +(y-b)^2=b^2 
\end{eqnarray*}
To summarise ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
x & =& \frac{a b^2}{a^2+b^2} \ a & =& \frac{x^2+y^2}{2x} \\
y & =& \frac{a^2 b}{a^2+b^2} \ b & =& \frac{x^2+y^2}{2y} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The problem with this solution is that suppose I want only the circles on the y-axis; then it's not possible to set $a=0$.

Comment: The space represented by $(a=0,b)$ you would expect to be $1$ dimensional but it collapses to a point ... the origin.

Comment: Precisely. But that's problematic for me because I really wanted the circles along one axis only.

Comment: I can maybe adjust this coordinate system somehow http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent-SphereCoordinates.html?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your coordinate system ? ... Maybe it is time for another question (referring back to this question) & explaining the bigger picture ?... "sample a function of the form f(ρ,θ)=g(Cρ(cosθ,sinθ−1))f(ρ,θ)=g(Cρ(cos⁡θ,sin⁡θ−1))." in order to ?